# How to get less white space at the start of first page of book

Tags: thesis

I am writing my starting page of the thesis in Latex, however there is one last bit I cannot seem to solve. 
There is too much white space in the first part of the page, as you can see here:

[image]

I have no idea how to solve this problem. The document class is "book".
This is how I defined my front page:

```
\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%

    \let\footnotesize\small

    \let\footnoterule\relax

    \let\footnote\thanks

    \chapter*{\makebox[\linewidth]{\@title}}

    \begin{center}

         \includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo}

         \vskip\dimexpr 7em-40\p@\relax%

         {\large \lineskip 0.4em%

         \textsc{Bachelor of Science in Mathematical Engineering}\\

         \vskip 0.4cm

         \textsc{Bachelor degree thesis}    \\

         \vskip 1cm

         \Huge\textbf{Parallelisation of matrix vector product}

         \begin{tabular}[t]{c}  \@author \end{tabular}\par}%

\vskip 4cm

\noindent

\parbox[t]{.5\textwidth}{\raggedright

Supervisor:\\

Prof. Name Surname}

\hfill

\parbox[t]{.2\textwidth}{\raggedleft

Candidate:\\

 Name Surname

   }%

\vskip 3em%

{\large \@date \par}%

\end{center}\par

\@thanks

\vfill\null\setcounter{footnote}{0}

\thispagestyle{empty}\addtocounter{page}{-1}

}

\makeatother
```

I tried using \title{\vspace{-3cm}My tile} and it doesn't work for me. Neither does the command \setlength{\droptitle}{-3cm}.

Any help?

Comment: Even though the document class is given as `book`, it seems like you're using a template that defines how `\maketitle` is printed, correct? If so, the required adjustments would rely on how `\maketitle` is defined. Can you provide a link to this template?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I will edit the post in a second.

Comment: Add some negative vertical space `\vspace*{-50pt}` before `\chapter*{\makebox[\linewidth]{\@title}}`. However, this is a university template, so I am not sure that changing the layout is a good idea.

Comment: I have been successful using your MWE and inserting 
`\vspace{-5cm}`  after the line
` \vskip\dimexpr 7em-40\p@\relax%`, but I agree w/ Ruixi Zhang.

Answer (score 1):

The `\maketitle` issues a `\chapter*`. By default, this chapter starts out with a 50pt vertical space. You can insert a quick hack before the `\chapter*` that updates what is inserted before the title.

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\vspace}[2]{}% Remove vertical space
\chapter*{\centering\@title}
\endgroup
```

The above removes the inserted `\vspace*{<len>}` by redefining it to capture its two arguments (the `*` and the `<len>`). If you want a different vertical gap, you can redefine `\vspace` to meet your needs:

```
\begingroup
\let\oldvspace\vspace
\renewcommand{\vspace}[2]{\oldvspace*{20pt}}% Change 20pt to whatever you want
\chapter*{\centering\@title}
\endgroup
```